# Why do I need cast twice to silence a -Werror=bad-function-cast warning

Tags: c, casting, gcc-warning

I have a following simple code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static uint8_t getStatus(void) 
{
    return 123u;
}

bool getError(void)
{

    bool error =  (bool)getStatus();
    return error;
}
```

And I get a following warning from gcc:

```
error: cast from function call of type 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to non-matching type '_Bool' [-Werror=bad-function-cast]
```

From gcc manual:

> -Wbad-function-cast (C and Objective-C only)
>       Warn whenever a function call is cast to a non-matching type. For example, warn if int malloc() is cast to anything *

So there are 3 interesting situation. Only 2 of them all allowed by gcc, but I don't see any potential difference between them.

```
bool error =  getStatus(); //THIS IS OK
return error;


bool error = (bool)getStatus(); //THIS IS BAD
return error;


bool error =  (bool)(uint8_t)getStatus(); //THIS IS OK!
return error;
```

So I have 3 questions:

1. Why I can't cast a result from getStatus() to bool.
2. Why I need to explicity cast result from getStatus to uint8_t and after that I can cast to bool.
3. How the Werror=bad-function-cast flag can help me to find (or avoid) an issue, and which kind of issue?

Comment: "*this flag*" which flag?

Comment: What do you want cast at all?

Comment: from gcc docs: "-Wbad-function-cast (C and Objective-C only)
Warn when a function call is cast to a non-matching type. For example, warn if a call to a function returning an integer type is cast to a pointer type."

Comment: @alk 1. thanks I thought "this flag" is obvious - fixed

Comment: @alk 2. good point. As Antti Haapala described casting an uint to bool this is totally redundant.

Comment: @Paweł Dymowski your quoted docs is already inside my question. I know How -Wbad-function-cast works, I don't know only the purpose...

Answer (score 2):

One reason for the behaviour is given in the excerpt that you provided: in C89 (but not in C99, C11, C17), it is acceptable to call a function without providing an explicit declaration. Then for example if you did not `#include <stdlib.h>`, then it is implicitly considered having the declaration `int malloc()`. And if you *then* use [the **bad habit of casting** the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc):

```
char *foo = (char*)malloc(42);
```

then you've masked a grave error. Unfortunately `char *foo = (char*)malloc(42);` would even then compile fine, whereas `char *foo = malloc(42);` would cause a diagnostic message be printed.

The rule of thumb is to **never** cast the return value of a function call.

Note that the conversion to `_Bool` from `uint8_t` does not need a *cast* (an explicit conversion), it can be done with *an implicit (castless) conversion*, hence the existence of any cast would be at least a stylistic mistake.

Comment: "*castless conversion*" is aka "implicit conversion".

Comment: Interesting a Finn misses a vowel ... ;>, but that's probably because you have so many ...

Comment: @alk hmm what where? :D

Comment: ---> `stdlb.h` ;)

Comment: @alk ... oops :P

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks a lot for you answer. _The rule of thumb is to never cast the return value of a function call._ - Is quite surprising for me.